# Facebook company pages, why some are simple urls and some are strange long urls?

Tags: url, facebook, page, clean-urls

I'm trying to set up this *damn FB* page for the company where I'm working for.

I think it's probably useless stuff, but I want to give a try.

I came up with this page:

```
www.facebook.com/pages/Poste-Certificateit-PEC-per-societa/168391856527591
```

Then I saw company pages with simple URLs, like this:

```
www.facebook.com/serverplan.it
```

I thought my 1st url could be re-written also as `www.facebook.com/Poste-Certificateit-PEC-per-societa`, but it does not work.

So why some **company pages** have simple URLs and some others need that long URLs?

Or what am I doing wrong?!

Thanks!

---

And BTW, if I'm on the wrong FB approach attempting to create *company page*, I mean if you think a *group page* or something else might be better from a Internet Marketing POV, plz let me know and exaplain. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A page has to have 25 fans/likes before they can select a vanity URL. If a page doesn't have enough fans/likes or doesn't choose a vanity URL they will use the default one assigned to them by Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

as John said you need at least `25 likes` of that page to be able to customize the url.

Once you get `25 likes/fans` go to `facebook.com/username` and you can customize it there.